# How to run fsck on a simfs filesystem under openvz

Tags: linux, openvz, fsck

How do you do a fsck on a simfs filesystem under OpenVZ?  You're supposed to not run fsck on a mounted FS.  Can you just fsck the image (/vz/private/100 or whatever it's called)?

Sorry I can't tag simfs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simfs is not an actual filesystem; it's a map to a directory on the host (by default `/vz/private/<veid>`). To check the filesystem, you have to check the *host* filesystem from the *host*, which also means you have to bring down every container on the host. If you believe it's necessary to check the filesystem, schedule a maintenance period and notify all the customers with containers on that host.